# Assign properties to possible components that can be defined inside a QML component

Tags: javascript, qt, qml

As a newbie to qml/qt programming, I would like to solve following issue;

MyComponent1.qml:

```
import QtQuick 2.0

Rectangle {
    width: 100
    height: 100
    border.color: "black"
    border.width: 5

    Text {
         height: 20
         anchors.bottom: parent.bottom
    }
}
```

MyComponent2.qml

```
import QtQuick 2.0
Rectangle {
    MyComponent1{   
       //here can be added any kind of component Rectangle or other components
       Rectangle {
         anchors.top: parent.top
       }
    }
    MyComponent1{   
       //here can be added any kind of component Rectangle or other components
       Rectangle {
         anchors.top: parent.top
       }
    }
    MyComponent1{   
       //here can be added any kind of component Rectangle or other components
       Rectangle {
         anchors.top: parent.top
       }
    }
}
```

I want to achieve that Rectangle Component which is written under of comment lines in MyComponent2.qml have some properties which will be predefined (like anchors.top: parent.top) in MyComponent1.qml.

For this example: 
"anchors.top: parent.top" is written 3 times within code in MyComponent2.qml.

Can we define it one time in MyComponent1.qml and apply it to all of 3 predefined Rectangle Components in MyComponent2.qml?

My goal is to increase the reusability of the code.

Thank you all in advance.

Comment: define another component which will contain `Rectangle { anchors.top: parent.top; }` and insert it instead

Comment: Thank you for your answer.. @folibis But problem is that I don't know whether my component is Rectangle. It is interchangeable. Maybe there are 20-30 kinds which I can replace instead of.

Comment: Ok, define `property var MyAnchor: parent.top;` inside your component and then get it inside a child component: `anchors.top: parent.MyAnchor`

Comment: A solution may be to iterate the children of MyComponent1 and set the appropriate properties inside `onChildrenChanged` of MyComponent1.

Answer (score 0):

Use this property alias inside MyComponent1:

```
myRect : rectId
```

And use this inside MyComponent2 to redefine anchors of rectangle:

```
myRect.anchors.top : parent.top
```